# pushViewController set duration of animation

Tags: ios

I am using this code to present a UIviewController:

```
-(IBAction)openWoodenPage3:(id)sender{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerWoodenPage3"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
}
```

The animation lasts 3 seconds, but I want to change this to 7sec. How can I do that? And If I wanted to change the side from right to left?

Comment: 3 seconds? That's awful long for a navigation controller push. Do you mean .3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will need to do everything by hand in a custom implementation, and use the following methods:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"abc" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7]; // seconds
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

// move stuff

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Also, push animations are of a fixed 0.3 (not 3) seconds, as well as many other standard animations in iOS like keyboard appearance, modal presentations, etc.

Comment: Apple recommends using the block based methods instead of these ever since iOS 4.

Comment: @rdelmar I would love to see Apple reject apps that don't use block based UIView animations (just a wild fantasy of mine :))